# How to import a function with different number of params

Tags: elixir

Let's say I have a module:

```
defmodule Request do

  def send(url, body \\ "", headers \\ [], opts \\ []) do
     .. some code
  end

  ... other functions ... 

end
```

And I need to import only the `send` function, so I would write something like this:

```
import Request, only: [send: 4]
```

but the problem here is that the compiler will give me an error saying that `send\1` is not defined if I use the `send` function passing only the url param and accepting defaults for the rest of the params.

So I wonder if there is a way to import the entire `send` function without importing `send\1`, `send\2` and `send\3`

It probably makes more sense to just use the function accessing it through the module itself as in `Request.send` but I am still interested in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `send/1` as you haven't imported it (as you identified.)

Your options are:

```
import Request
import Request: :functions
import Request, only: [send: 1, send: 2, send: 3, send: 4]
import Request, except: [notsend: 1, also_notsend: 2]
```

You can read the docs at https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2